# Convert a string of 0-F into a byte array in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am attempting to decrypt a number encrypted by another program that uses the BouncyCastle library for Java.

In Java, I can set the key like this:  `key = Hex.decode("5F3B603AFCE22359");`

I am trying to figure out how to represent that same step in Ruby.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get Integer — just `str.hex`. You may get byte array in several ways:

```
str.scan(/../).map(&:hex)
[str].pack('H*').unpack('C*')
[str].pack('H*').bytes.to_a
```

See [other options for `pack/unpack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#method-i-unpack) and [examples (by codeweblog)](https://web.archive.org/web/20150131204609/http://www.codeweblog.com/ruby-string-pack-unpack-detailed-usage/).

Comment: Isn't the `.to_a` superfluous?
If someone cares about performance with huge Strings (10M hex digits): `str.scan(/../).map(&:hex)`: 1.061567s, `[str].pack('H*').unpack('C*')`: 0.175744s `[str].pack('H*').bytes.to_a`: 0.149195s

Answer (score 3):

For a string `str`:

```
"".tap {|binary| str.scan(/../) {|hn| binary << hn.to_i(16).chr}}
```

Comment: Nice! It's a style thing, but personally I'd rephrase it as: `str.scan(/../).inject(""){|binary,hn| binary << hn.to_i(16).chr}`.

Comment: Note: [`str.scan(/../)` performs way worse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772410/convert-a-string-of-0-f-into-a-byte-array-in-ruby/3772446#comment131543186_3772446). This might be irrelevant for 'normal' numbers as of 1-16 bytes