# What is the equivalent of Nodejs Buffer in Ruby?

Tags: node.js, ruby, buffer

I know in Nodejs there is a Buffer module:

```
import { Buffer } from "buffer/";

// node = ...
// labelSha = ...
Buffer.from(node + labelSha, "hex");
```

what's the equivalent in Ruby ?

thanks

Comment: [IO::Buffer](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/IO/Buffer.html) is close, although has specific mmap file and ruby string functionality attached to the generic buffer memory store

Comment: @Matt +1 for mentioning IO:Buffer, but while [IO::Buffer#new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/IO/Buffer.html#method-c-new) accepts a size argument, I don't think it's really meant to do what the OP is trying to do. I suppose it could be made to, but I'm not sure why that would be better than truncating a String or Array of characters/bytes, especially considering that `buf = IO::Buffer.new(3); buf.set_string("test")` would raise `Specified offset+length exceeds data size! (ArgumentError)`. Not saying it couldn't be done; it just seems like a lot of work for very little gain in this case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a string of 0-F into a byte array in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772410/convert-a-string-of-0-f-into-a-byte-array-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Ruby Strings and Arrays are Dynamic, Not Fixed-Length

There really isn't a direct comparison in Ruby's core or standard library, although I suppose you could create your own simulation of one. A [Node.js Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer) is a fixed-length sequence of bytes. Depending on what that means for your use case, you can use one or more of:

- [String#bytes](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-bytes)
- [String#byteslice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-byteslice)
- [Array#pack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Array.html#method-i-pack) and [String#unpack](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-unpack)

to access the stored bytes, but neither String nor Array objects in Ruby are really fixed-length unless you freeze them. However, frozen objects are (for most purposes) immutable, so that's really not quite the same thing. As a result, it's basically up to you to truncate, slice, replace by index, or otherwise drop elements to maintain a "fixed size."

If you plan to do this a lot, you could create a subclass of String or Array with a getter or setter method that truncates the contents of an instance variable to your desired size every time you access it. That's most likely your best bet, although it's certainly possible someone has already written a gem that provides this functionality. [The Ruby Toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) and [RubyGems.org](https://rubygems.org/) are your best bets for searching for gems that provide implementations of fixed-size or circular buffers if you don't want to implement your own, but the options and quality will vary greatly as they aren't part of Ruby's built-in classes.

Comment: really helpful , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone!

after spending 2 hours, I also wrote my own version of implementation:

```
  def nodejs_buffer_to_hex origin_string
    i = 0 
    result = []
    temp = ""
    loop do
      break if i == origin_string.length
      temp += origin_string[i]
      if i % 2 == 1
        result << temp
        temp = ""
      end 
      i += 1
    end 

    result = result.map do |e| 
      "0x#{e}".hex
    end 
    return result
  end
```

and usage:

```
nodejs_buffer_to_hex "ce159cf3"  # => [206,21,156,243]
```

Comment: Alternatively `'ce159cf3'.scan(/../).map(&:hex)` or `['ce159cf3'].pack('H*').unpack('C*')`